# Adding two corresponding array elements and return the resultant array

Tags: c, scope, function-definition, variable-length-array, storage-duration

Facing segmentation fault in the following code . Can anyone help me fix it?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int* multiply(int *arr1, int *arr2, int m);

int main(void){
    int m = 0;
    
    
    printf("Enter size of array1 and array2 >");
    scanf("%d",&m);

    int arr1[m],  arr2[m];
        printf("First array>");

    for(int i = 0; i < m; ++i){
        scanf("%d", &arr1[i]);
    }
    printf("Second array> ");
    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
       scanf("%d", &arr2[j]);

    
    
    int* result = multiply(arr1, arr2, m);

    for(int i = 0; i < m; ++i){
        printf("%d ", result[i]);
    }
    


}

int* multiply(int *arr1, int *arr2, int m){
    int res[m];
    printf("ok");
    for(int i = 0; i < m; ++i){
        res[i] = arr1[i] + arr2[i];
    }
    printf("ok");
    return res;
}
```

Output should show like

Enter size of array1 and array2 >3

First array>5 1 7

Second array> 2 4 2

The resultant > 7 5 9

My output

Enter size of array1 and array2 >3

First array>5 1 7

Second array> 2 4 2

Segmentation fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program has undefined behavior because the function `multiply` returns a pointer to the local array `res` that will not be alive after exiting the function. So after exiting the function the returned pointer will be invalid.

```
int* multiply(int *arr1, int *arr2, int m){
    int res[m];
    printf("ok");
    for(int i = 0; i < m; ++i){
        res[i] = arr1[i] + arr2[i];
    }
    printf("ok");
    return res;
}
```

You need to allocate memory dynamically for the array.
Also the parameters that denote arrays should have qualifier `const` because passed arrays are not changed within the function.

The function can be declared and defined the following way.

```
int * multiply( const int *arr1, const int *arr2, size_t n )
{
    int *res = NULL;

    if ( n != 0 && ( res = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) ) ) != NULL )
    {
        for( size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i )
        {
            res[i] = arr1[i] + arr2[i];
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

In main you should write

```
int* result = multiply(arr1, arr2, m);

if ( result != NULL )
{
    for(int i = 0; i < m; ++i){
        printf("%d ", result[i]);
    }
}

free( result );
```

Answer (score -1):

The return varible of your function is local so it does not exist outside of the function scope, what I mean once you return a stack allocated variable from a function it scopes ends right then and there (unless that variable is defined as static), it is erased from the memory.

There are three fixes for it:

1. make your return value variable static (this will preserve its value even when function's scope end);
2. make your function void and instead pass the return value as a parameter to your function.
3. use global variables for storing your result (highly discouraged though, but in your case it wont be a bad practice).

Answer (score -2):

In the multiply function, pass *m* as a constant integer, because the size of array number is always a constant.

```
int* multiply(int *arr1, int *arr2, const int m){
    int res[m];
    printf("ok");
    for(int i = 0; i < m; ++i){
        res[i] = arr1[i] + arr2[i];
    }
    printf("ok");
    return res;
}
```

Do not forget to change the declaration of the function on line 3.